# Computed Column brackets lost in SSDT project

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-data-tools

I have a SSDT Project in Visual Studio 2015 which has a table definition as follows that includes a computed column.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [Id]    INT   NOT NULL,
    [Cost]  MONEY NULL,
    [Vat]   AS    (Cost * 0.2),
    [Total] AS    (Cost + (Cost * 0.2)),
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

When I deploy to SQL Server I get the following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Cost] [money] NULL,
    [Vat]  AS ([Cost]*(0.2)),
    [Total]  AS ([Cost]+[Cost]*(0.2)),
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

My question is why do the brackets in my computed column disappear? Do I need to select an option somewhere to preserve them or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed columns aren't stored as text. They're stored in an internal, efficient form. That means that, any elements of the definition that aren't critical to the actual meaning of the computed column aren't retained.

Since `*` has a higher precedence than `+`, `Cost + (Cost * 0.2)` and `[Cost]+[Cost]*(0.2)` have exactly the same meaning. The server doesn't generate extra brackets when precedence already takes care of matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the issue altogether:

```
[Cost]  MONEY NULL,
[Vat]   AS    (Cost * 0.2),
[Total] AS    (Cost + Vat),
```

Also, whilst this is off-topic, the above code will become a problem as soon as the VAT rate changes (which it will). Store the VAT percent as a decimal column in the table, rather than hard-coding the value as 0.2 - otherwise, when the rate changes, all of your historical calculations would change too, which you don't want.

Comment: My question is actually a simplification of my actual table structure. I have a VatRate column which replaces the 0.2 value. Also you can't use computed columns to compute another column, so your answer wouldn't work.